# Stripping "\" and "\n" from string

Tags: linux, ansible, jinja2

I have the below code in a variable. I want to strip the "" and "\n" characters. I have tried things like

```
variable | replace('\\','')
```

but it does not work. Any ideas?

Full contents of variable:

```
"\"v=DKIM1; k=rsa;\n \"p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAzlKOKQ/tPSqdrxM3ANorroiZU4LqUwFVkFwLY82qepGVqmaCbv4T52GcPx3YJE/GNu55e2iuzARUS3eqPOsTKrqrTpcovS5h8QTGMxvyd+yXfosCZ84TlQ8knG8RQHG8Z8vmxgjgvY9k89TA3doRacSmEBeHNFOYiRtL5ZpdF45Wzpj19gz+bV4z2TmFE3dxPThTcicn/FMchL\"\n \"nfVj5LfUqK2x+HCvI8hCXGfUiD5zsTd5VKOVwpn2t1p/kOjaY6++RA19DDz+oEoCTBh2QS7pCmb65dshiR3lXKbkbLaj4bEw6IHPyaDiHauYAa/Ra61HEsYoEci7P4Jc28gEXxjwIDAQAB\""
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ code :
ASCII code for '\n' and "" are 10 and 34

```
string str="";
for(int i=0;i<sample.length();i++){
   if(sample[i]!=10 and  sample[i]!=34){
     str+=sample[i];
                    }
}
cout<< str;
```